# Laravel-5.3 : Error: View [main] not found

Tags: laravel, view, controller, routes, laravel-5.3

I have encountered a problem with a view routing :

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [main] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\store\resources\views\currencies\index.blade.php)
```

And

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [main] not found.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

**What I am trying to do :**

My Route:

```
Route::resource('currencies', 'CurrencyController');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // create a variable and store all the posts in it from the database
    $currencies = Currency::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(5);
    //$currencies = Currency::all();

    // return a view and pass in the above variable
    return view('currencies.index')->withCurrencies($currencies);
}
```

And my view (resources/views/currencies/index.blade.php):

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| Settings - Currencies')

@section('content')

@endsection
```

Can anyone take me to the right direction ?
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display a page with the view `main.blade.php` as the layout for your page. That is what [`@extends('main')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#template-inheritance) does.

It seems the file `main.blade.php` does not exist in your view root. Create this file or edit the link in this view.

Comment: I knew I am having a silly mistake, I have a page named index.blade.php for my layout page, but i didn't changed the extends file name to @extends('index') ...Thanks buddy !

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Consider marking this answer as the solution if this solved the problem. :)